# Can't bind to 'settings' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2-multiselect'

Tags: angular, frontend, angular2-template

Everybody
I am trying to use angular2-multiselect and have issue.
My angular version is 11

This is issue message

```
Error: src/app/main/stores/stores-list/new-stores-sidebar/new-stores-sidebar.component.html:367:35 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2-multiselect'.
1. If 'angular2-multiselect' is an Angular component and it has 'data' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular2-multiselect' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

367             <angular2-multiselect [data]="itemList"
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/main/stores/stores-list/new-stores-sidebar/new-stores-sidebar.component.ts:11:16
    11   templateUrl: './new-stores-sidebar.component.html'
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component NewStoresSidebarComponent.


Error: src/app/main/stores/stores-list/new-stores-sidebar/new-stores-sidebar.component.html:369:15 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'settings' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2-multiselect'.      
1. If 'angular2-multiselect' is an Angular component and it has 'settings' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular2-multiselect' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

369               [settings]="settings"
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/main/stores/stores-list/new-stores-sidebar/new-stores-sidebar.component.ts:11:16
    11   templateUrl: './new-stores-sidebar.component.html'
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component NewStoresSidebarComponent.
```

This is issue image

[image]

This is html code.

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="itemList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
  [settings]="settings" 
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
  (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" 
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" 
  (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

This is .ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-stores-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './new-stores-sidebar.component.html'
})

export class NewStoresSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  public itemList = [];
  public selectedItems = [];
  public settings = {};

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param {CoreSidebarService} _coreSidebarService
   */
  constructor(
    private _coreSidebarService: CoreSidebarService,
    private _toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.closeImage = 'assets/images/close.png';

    this.itemList = [
      { "id": 1, "itemName": "India", "category": "asia" },
      { "id": 2, "itemName": "Singapore", "category": "asia pacific" },
      { "id": 3, "itemName": "Germany", "category": "Europe" },
      { "id": 4, "itemName": "France", "category": "Europe" },
      { "id": 5, "itemName": "South Korea", "category": "asia" },
      { "id": 6, "itemName": "Sweden", "category": "Europe" }
    ];

    this.selectedItems = [
      { "id": 1, "itemName": "India" },
      { "id": 2, "itemName": "Singapore" },
      { "id": 4, "itemName": "Canada" }
    ];

    this.settings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      text: "Select Fields",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      searchPlaceholderText: 'Search Fields',
      enableSearchFilter: true,
      badgeShowLimit: 5,
      groupBy: "category"
    };
  }

  loadDataSet1(){
    this.selectedItems = [];
    this.itemList = [ { "id": 1, "itemName": "Apple", "category": "fruits" },
      { "id": 2, "itemName": "Banana", "category": "fruits" },
      { "id": 5, "itemName": "Tomatoe", "category": "vegetables" },
      { "id": 6, "itemName": "Potatoe", "category": "vegetables" }];
  }
  loadDataSet2(){
    this.selectedItems = [];
    this.itemList = [
      { "id": 1, "itemName": "India", "category": "asia" },
      { "id": 2, "itemName": "Singapore", "category": "asia pacific" },
      { "id": 3, "itemName": "Germany", "category": "Europe" },
      { "id": 4, "itemName": "France", "category": "Europe" },
      { "id": 5, "itemName": "South Korea", "category": "asia" },
      { "id": 6, "itemName": "Sweden", "category": "Europe" }
    ];
  }
  onItemSelect(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.selectedItems);
  }
  OnItemDeSelect(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.selectedItems);
  }
  onSelectAll(items: any) {
    console.log(items);
  }
  onDeSelectAll(items: any) {
    console.log(items);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Is there any solution? I guess this depends on version.

Comment: Make sure you have imported the corresponding module in your app/tests.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you did...but...just in case:

Had you import the AngularMultiSelectModule in your app.module.ts?:

`app.module.ts`

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    AngularMultiSelectModule,
  ]
  // ...
})
```

[Source](https://cuppalabs.github.io/components/multiselectDropdown/)

Comment: yes, I have added in app.module.ts, but it is not working.

Comment: I think this is angular version problem

Comment: My angular version is 11